# Python cannot import modules

Tags: python3

I am running Windows 10 and python 3.6.3
Python no longer has the ability to import modules to any of my codes, including codes that previously worked. I keep getting the error that no module can be found for anything.

Comment: What are the results of `where python` and `python -V`? What are the results of `where pip`? Have you tried running `py -3.6 [some script name]`? How did you install Python (from https://python.org, via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/), etc.?) You say that no packages will work but which have you tried specifically? Please edit your question to include as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

please explain your question with some code so that it's easy to figure out what caused the problem.
My suggestions:
1. Check if you have your main file (the file into which you import from other files) in the same directory as the imported files.
2. Check if the file name is the same as before.
3. Try reinstalling python3
4. If you are using IDEs like PyCharm, Spider, etc. Try checking the import statement in python IDLE if this works then try reinstalling the IDE.
5. Try setting the path to python.